# Using Robotframework to scroll the window but not working

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I'm trying to scroll the window using robotframework selenium library

```
Execute JavaScript  window.scrollTo(1,500)
```

Tried the above code but it will execute for the first time and further it will not scroll.

```
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0,200)

Execute JavaScript    window.scrollBy(0,200)

Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Even these has the same issue

Comment: Hi Ullas, could `Scroll Element Into View` keyword be useful for you?

https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser